# How to display an alert box through ajax when my show action is loaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Sorry for this newbie question, I am trying to display a simple alert box through Ajax when my galleries/show view is loaded. (After I would like to display content instead of this alert box)

Here is my code so far:

#### galleries_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html # show.html.erb
    end
  end
```

#### application.js

```
// Tell Rails to use .js
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")} 
})

$(document).ready(function(){

  // How can I load show.js.erb ?
  $('body').load() 

});
```

#### show.js.erb

```
alert('ajax works!');
```

I can't figure how to make it works. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails returns `show.js.erb` (after evaluation) when you hit `Gallery#show` from an AJAX call. So, you can get the contents returned with [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get({'gallery/show/some_id_number', dataType: script});
```

The `dataType: script` property will cause jQuery to execute what's returned (i.e. the contents of the evaluated `show.js.erb`).

Comment: Thanks so much just need to think about the :id as I am using a slug. regards

Comment: Glad it helped. If you're using slugs, you should be able to replace `some_id_number` with `some_slug_name`.

Answer (score 2):

Remote everything in application js

in show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Get Gallery", gallery_url(@gallery), :remote => true %>
```

Reload /galleries/show/:id
Click the link

Comment: Great solution if you want a hyperlink, +1. Mine's more suited for behind-the-scenes usage; I can see yours being more broadly applicable.

Comment: @alex - not sure what he is exactly wanting to do here.  I thought a link would help him understand how rails works with ajax.  The biggest problem is :id of the gallery

Comment: Yeah I agree. Slapped my head when I saw yours, a much more elegant Ruby-ish way of making an AJAX request. Both equally valid answers given the question IMO.

Comment: I m gonna try that to. The only thing is I don't want to click in any link. As you said :id bothers me. As I want to perform this js in every show page, I figure to use html5 tag. Thanks a lot for yours answers, it helps me a lot!

Comment: I am curious why you need an ajax request at all.  Could you now just use a partial?

Comment: I am using amazon s3 to display images in galleries and it takes a bit of time to load them fully. What I am trying to achieve (my final result) is to load images in the background then when they are fully load they will be displayed. Yes at first i used a partial :)

Comment: @benoitr - okay, so I don't think that you need ajax here at all. In fact, I don't think that it will have the effect that you want. You could achieve the result by using the the `load` event on images. Hide them with CSS then on image load, display them.

Comment: Thanks it seems really nicer! Yesterday I posted a question about this, if you want to answer with this I'll accept it. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448348/how-to-load-a-gallery-content-after-images-are-loading-in-the-background)